# Changing the position of Joomla 3.2 tags

Tags: joomla, tags, overriding, joomla3.2

I have added some tags and linked these to an article. On the front end the tags appear on top (i.e. before) the article text. Instead I would like to display them at the bottom (i.e. after) the article.

I assume I have to make an override of layouts/joomla/content/tags.php

Comment: yes, you will have to make a template override and possibly apply some CSS. Was there a particular question you had?

Comment: @Lodder Not quite, I am not sure what I need to change in the template override

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the following file:

```
components/com_content/views/tmpl/default.php
```

Once done, open this file in your override location and go to line 157 and you will see the following:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags)) : ?>
    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Move this section of code somewhere futher down in the file to suit your needs

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved by simply changing the Position Of Article Info to "Below" in Options Tab in Joomla Menu. The Joomla menu has to be of Type "Article"

No need to create any override.
Hope this helps.
See attached screenshot.
[image: Position of Joomla Tags]